# No tags return from tag_recent_media

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

Hello I'm playing with the python instagram API and I'm using this example:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)

recent_media, next_ = api.tag_recent_media( count = 20, max_tag_id = '', tag_name = 'cats' ) )

for media in recent_media:
    print media.tags  # attempt to get tags associated with each media
```

When I run it, some times it says that media does not have "tags" attribute. But I'm searching for tag_recent_media, how is possible to the media not have tags?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the media doesnt have any tags, and a comment has it?

Try to check that, because a media with tags on comments will also be returned by /recent endpoint.

Comment: I changed my code in order to debug it, will run it until this error happens again, thanks for the tip!

Comment: it happend again, I was searching for the tag "chá" and the program stopped working in this link: https://instagram.com/p/2T3Xn1Apqq/, strange because it doesn't have any hashtag = "chá" neither in the caption nor in the comments, why this post was in the results?

Comment: it happened gain... https://instagram.com/p/1wffEGwWQS/ maybe something wrong with the API?

Comment: the hashtags are on the first comment. check that out. #chá is there.

Comment: strange, I can't find here, I lookup in the source code of both pages and could find it, I just found: "chá" without the hashtag...

Comment: the web view doesnt show up all comments yet.. you can only see that on your phone. check out this print screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/16s7kvkgtvhwe23/Screenshot_2015-05-07-16-37-43.png?dl=0

Comment: oh.. good to know.. I added this condition to my code 'if hasattr( result , 'tags' ):' I think that will solve the problem... thanks @PedroCasado !